# Advanced GUI and database in c#

Tags: c#, database, user-interface

Do you have any idea how to present all rows from let's say table with the possibility to click on particular row and open that way another window to edit?

I've got no idea how to create this. I would like to avoid access like creation by built-in wizards in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Perhaps you know where I can find more information.

Answer (score 3):

Execute a query which retrieves an overview of the records that you want to display.

When you double-click a row, you retrieve the records that represent that entity, and display it in another window...

That's in a nutshell how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

For a web application you may want to look at this [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stc0szde(VS.80).aspx) as MSDN.  You can find a [winform walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984462(VS.71).aspx) at MSDN as well.  Though you say that you prefer doing it without the designers, I suggest that you go through the walkthrough using the designer and look at the code that it produces as a sample of how you could do it by hand.  You could then adapt the example as needed for your purposes.  For more references try googling "master detail view."

Answer (score 0):

well i would use wpf with a stackpanel of listboxes

the rows are dynamically added to the stackpanel. 
the listboxes contain textfields that are databind -ed to mouseclickevents and onchanged events.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/WPFTutorial.aspx